# HQL join problem

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have no problem writing sql for the following problem. However, I would like to write it as HQL or ICriteria. I am using fluent nhibernate and the latest nhibernate. The situation:

There are 6 classes A B C D AC AD. B inherits from A. AC represents a m:m relationship between A and C and AD represents a m:m relationship between A and D. Let us assume that all classes have an ID column. I would like to count the number of Cs and Ds B is associated with.

There is no IList of, for example, Cs in A (and B for that matter). Still the classes are associated ...

Here is some code (simplified):

```
public class A : Entity
{

}

public class B : A
{

}

public class C : Entity
{

}

public class D : Entity
{

}

public class AC : Entity
{
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
    public virtual C C { get; set; }
}

public class AD : Entity
{
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
    public virtual D D { get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible to use HQL and ‘left join’ (to also show the Bs that have zero Cs and Ds) in my particular case?

Thanks.

Christian

PS:

I have played a bit with theta style joins but did not get the expected results and I don’t think ‘left joins’ are possible here aren’t they?

PPS:

This theta-style join kind of works but only if B is assciated with at least 1 C and D:

```
select 
    B.Id, 
    count(distinct AC.C.Id),
    count(distinct AD.D.Id)
from AC AC, AD AD, B B
where AC.A.Id = B.Id and AD.A.Id = B.Id
group by B.Id
```

Comment: can you please provide the classes as code? It would be much easier to understand which properties are available.

Comment: done. see class code. is this ok? please note that things are simplified.

Comment: Why have you got classes to represent the M:M relationship? You're not associating any extra data, so it seems frivolousness and confusing

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using two one-to-many relationships to model a many-to-many one. This gives you more flexibility in the long run especially when the many-to-many has additional columns ...

Comment: These aren't one-to-many relations, these are many-to-one relations. OO relations aren't bidirectional as DB relations are. You don't have any list in your object model, nor any back relations. This makes it so hard to navigate.

Comment: @Stefan: Can you please explain: "one-to-many relations, these are many-to-one relations" IMHO there is a one-to-many relation between A and AC and A and AD ... also what is a "back relation". Where would you put an IList<?> then without removing the classes that represents the many-to-many relations?

Comment: You are thinking in relational tables, not in OOD. A reference to A is many-to-one (because there is only one referenced) a IList<A> is a one-to-many (or many-to-many) relation. "Back relations" simply means that you can navigate both directions. It is mapped using inverse="true". There is only one foreign key in the database for this.

Comment: Thanks. My background is relational so sorry about that. Ill have a look at your answer. do you think I can add IList<C> Cs { get; private set; } to A (using fluent nh) without changing the underlying db?

Comment: yes, I'm quite sure you can. Just map it as a `set` of many-to-many, using the link table and foreign keys of the database.

Comment: Is this what you mean in fnh mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Cs).Table("AC") ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use two queries and sum the result:

```
int numberOfLinks;

numberOfLinks = session
  .CreateQuery(
    @"select count(*)
    from AC ac
    where ac.A = :b"
  .SetEntity("b", myB)
  .UniqueResult<int>();

numberOfLinks += session
  .CreateQuery(
    @"select count(*)
    from AD ad
    where ad.A = :b"
  .SetEntity("b", myB);
```

I can't see a way to make it with a single query. Your classes don't seem to be designed for that kind of query... (which *may* be a sign that the design isn't appropriate, but doesn't need to be. It depends of how typical this query is for your application.)

---

In contrast, if you *had* these navigation paths, without questioning the relation classes:

```
public class A : Entity
{
  IList<AC> ACs { get; private set; }
  IList<AD> ADs { get; private set; }
}
```

you would get the size of the lists by:

```
numberOfLinks = session.CreateQuery(
  @"select size(ACs) + size(ADs)
  from B
  where ...")
```

or even easier in memory :-)

```
numberOfLinks = myB.ADs.Count + myB.ACs.Count;
```

---

Completely removing the relation classes, it could look like this:

```
public class A : Entity
{
  IList<C> Cs { get; private set; }
  IList<D> Ds { get; private set; }
}

public class C : Entity
{
  IList<A> As { get; private set; }
}

public class D : Entity
{
  IList<A> As { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't seem to have to remove the relational classes (the ones that represent the many-to-many relations). This gives me the flexibility to add further columns to AC and AD. Simply putting, for example, IList<C> into A and mapping it using mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Cs).Table("ACs"); seems to do the trick or do I miss something?

Comment: The mapping looks good so far, but you don't have the relation classes mapped. If you want to keep them, map a list of AC. I wouldn't keep them, they're just more complicated and you could still add them in the future (remember the YAGNI principle).

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by: you don't have the relation classes mapped. Does mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Cs).Table("ACs") not map them from the A point of view (I also included IList<C> in A)?

Comment: "you don't have the relation classes mapped" means: the classes called `AC` and `AD` aren't mapped. You can remove them from the class model. If these classes are important for you for any reason, this isn't an option for you. The relations between A => C and A => D are still mapped.